# MassTransit IBusControl.ScheduleRecurringSend generates the same MessageId for the same type of scheduled events

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, masstransit, quartz.net

I have a console application for the purposes of using quartz scheduling with masstransit. The related code is located in `Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)` implementation of IHostedService.

It looks like the following code

```
        await _bus.ScheduleRecurringSend(new Uri($"queue_uri"),
            new CustomMessageSchedule(),
            new CustomMessage(),
            cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        var scheduler = await _schedulerFactory.GetScheduler(cancellationToken);
        scheduler.JobFactory = new MassTransitJobFactory(_bus, _jobFactory);
        await scheduler.Start(cancellationToken);
```

Scheduled messages are successfully published to the queue, but those are getting the same messageId. That causes some problems on a consumer side.

I've to make use of `IFilter<SendContext<CustomMessage>>` implementation, but it didn't work out. Maybe i wasn't using it right, but i'm not even sure if that's the right approach.

Any suggestions on the matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scheduled messages are not modified by Quartz before being sent, other than including a few additional message headers. It might make sense to generate a new `MessageId` for recurring messages (since they're not a one-and-done scheduled message like regularly scheduled messages).

However, as of right now the behavior is as expected.